# Compiler Error in C - expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token after ELSE statement

Tags: c, if-statement, gcc, token

Here’s a newbie question. I’m writing this simple if...else code, but the gcc compiler acuses that the ';' token is missing right after the else expression, even though I’ve never seen any C if...else code examples that includes this specific token before the function’s curly braces. Also, when I include the token after the 'else' function, the terminal outputs both if and else elements, so I’m completely lost here.

Compiler Error:

```
cclasses.c:15:2: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main ()
{
        int x;
        printf("\nEnter with negative or positive int.");
        scanf("%i", &x);

        if (x > 0)
        {
                printf("\nYou've entered positive int: %i\n", x);
        }
        else(x < 0)
        {
                printf("\nYou've entered negative int: %i\n", x);
        }

        printf("\nEND OF PROGRAM.\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: You missed an `if` after else

Comment: This is just a syntax error. You need `else if (...)` instead of `else (...)`. Also, `else` does not accept comparisons so it's just `else`, not `else (x < 0)`.

Comment: Thank you very much, guys. I've just deleted the (...) after else statement and it worked perfectly.

Comment: But then 0 will be considered negative to your program... Though, it's good to see there's progress!

Comment: Just added `else if (x == 0)` as you told and it went ok. Again, thank you very much!

Comment: In all honesty, I don't see this making a long-term contribution to Stack Overflow.  I think you could delete the question.  However, maybe you can't delete it since there are two answers, albeit one a self-answer and the other giving incorrect information from an inadequate web site.

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it's working all right.

```
     int main ()
{
        int x;
        printf("\nEnter with negative or positive int.");
        scanf("%i", &x);

        if (x > 0)
        {
                printf("\nYou've entered positive int: %i\n", x);
        }
        else if (x == 0)
        {
                printf("\nYou've entered zero/null: %i\n", x);
        }
        else
        {
                printf("\nYou've entered negative int: %i\n",x);
        }

        printf("\nEND OF PROGRAM.\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's supposed to be:

```
scanf("%d", &x);
```

- there is no "%i"

I used this site https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm as a reference.

Comment: [The `scanf` (and family) function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) do indeed have an `"%i"` format specifier. It's not commonly used though.

Comment: The `%i` conversion specification in `scanf()` was in C90, and is fine up until you are parsing dates and someone enters 08 or 09 for the day or month (or year); then `%i` appears to go astray — at least, at that point, it surprises people who don't realize that `0` in a C program is an octal constant, not a decimal constant.  (See C11 [§6.4.4 Integer constants](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.4.4).)

Comment: Also, get a better reference site — the information at tutorialspoint.com is woefully incomplete with no indication of its incompleteness.  Compare what it says with an authoritative site: for example, POSIX [`scanf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html) or C11 [§7.21.6.2 The `fscanf` function](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2).